# Spring 4.1.5 MVC @RequestParam(required = false, value = "somevalue") fails if a parameter is absent

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring mvc controller which is serving web service requests with multiple request parameters. All the parameters are marked `required = false`. Still if in the request a parameter is not available,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/deployNew", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<DeploymentId>  deploy(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(required = false, value = "abc") String abc, @RequestParam(required = false, value = "xyz") String xyz, @RequestParam(required = false, value = "uvw") String uvw,)  throws Exception;
```

I see the error

```
required string parameter 'param' is not present
```

If I give a blank value to the param, everything works fine as below. Parameters `abc` and `xyz` has a blank value, but still I am passing it.

```
curl -i -X POST -H Accept:application/json "http://localhost:8080/Test/service/deploy.do?abc=&xyz=&uvw=somevalue"
```

If I remove any of the above param it will throw the error.

```
curl -i -X POST -H Accept:application/json "http://localhost:8080/Test/service/deploy.do?uvw=somevalue"
```

My service is being used by multiple clients with a single endpoint which caused some parameters to be present at times. I need to handle all the scenarios. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the actual code just for sanity?

Comment: Could it be that for value you should have the param name and not somevalue? code snippets would be very helpful

Comment: As @BeauGrantham says - code snippet appreciated (probably just the method signature and the annotation), plus I would add the stack trace as well...

Comment: Your Content-Type header should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded I think.

Comment: Maybe try taking cURL out of the equation and just post with a very basic html form. I'm wondering if your issue is a cURL issue not a spring mvc controller issue.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. I can't reproduce your error and the parameter names you've posted don't match. It's hard to understand what you are running exactly.

Comment: @ManuelVieda I tried with Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. No luck.

Comment: @headlikearock tried out the html form. Same error.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use defaultValue

```
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "somevalue")
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#defaultValue--

Comment: i tried this. Not working I still see the error, Required String parameter 'abc' is not present

Comment: I think there is some problem when the parameter is String. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam
`Type conversion is applied automatically if the target method parameter type is not String`

try to put these String properties in one POJO with @ModelAttribute and change the signature for the method, I know is not a perfect solution but can work.

Comment: I used "defaultValue" and I still get the error.