# Optional RequestParam in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have below code

```
public ModelAndView springController(@ModelAttribute("param1") Object param1,
        @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) Object param2,
        BindingResult bindingResult)
```

I am not submitting any value from JSP for param2. 
I have also provided required=false for param2. But when I hit the submit button it gives 400 Bad Request error.

Thanks

Comment: What is the URL being hit, could you show us?

Comment: /secure/page/create

Comment: That's it? there is no value for `param1`?

Comment: its a post request

Comment: Another way to solve / allow to hit the request without providing the value for `param2` would be to provide default value `@RequestParam(value = "param2", defaultValue = "null", required = false) Object param2`

Comment: should work, look for the problem somewhere else

Comment: Still not working. If i am removing param2 it is working fine.

Comment: this is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599842/spring-4-1-5-mvc-requestparamrequired-false-value-somevalue-fails-if-a. Seems like they didn't really figure it out.

Comment: ..except for the `defaultValue` option of course.